# How to add plus 1 day to a timestamp in Cassandra SQL?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-4.0

I am trying to add 1 day to a timestamp field.

Below is what I have tried but not working:

```
select studentid, (course_date + 1) as nextday from students where studentid=123;
select studentid,(course_date/DAY+1DAY) as nextday from students where studentid=123;
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can specify a time component along with the date arithmetic.  In this case, changing `1` to `1d` (one day) solves this:

```
> SELECT studentid,course_date + 1d as nextday FROM students WHERE studentid=1;

 studentid | nextday
-----------+---------------------------------
         1 | 2022-01-04 06:00:00.000000+0000

(1 rows)
```

For more information, I recently wrote a blog post on the use of [Arithmetic Operators in Apache Cassandra 4.0](https://medium.com/building-the-open-data-stack/arithmetic-operators-in-apache-cassandra-4-0-c5a3185d683) as well as a [short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CzJSeIzQgDY) on this topic!  Below is a more comprehensive list of the valid time duration codes:

[image: Valid CQL time duration codes]